# What's the scoop with google analytics bindings?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, google-analytics, arm, static-libraries

I finally updated to newest monotouch / iOS5. project didn't link any more, which I eventually tracked down to some problem with the facebook and analytics libraries.

I found

https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/GoogleAnalytics

and made the project compile. But I know see that the main API of the library (TrackPageView) is blocked.

- Is there a fix needed on the google side for this? If yes, can you let me know what it is?
- Also, something else doesn't seem to be working for me. I followed instructions and added GoogleAnalytics.dll to project (which seems to have the .a file embedded as resource) and removed old flags adding to library. I get the following callstack:

`Unhandled Exception: MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown.  Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: -[GANAdHitIdGenerator adHitId]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x853b1d0
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging:bool_objc_msgSend_IntPtr_IntPtr_IntPtr_int_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr,int,intptr)
  at GoogleAnalytics.GANTracker.TrackEvent (System.String category, System.String action, System.String label, Int32 value, MonoTouch.Foundation.NSError& nsError) [0x00000] in :0 
  at BookOfMe.Analytics.LogEvent (BookOfMe.AnalyticsEvent analyticsEvent) [0x00024] in /Users/davidnotario/Projects/trunk/iOS/iPhone/Code/Core/Analytics.cs:31`

Answer (score 3):

It's a mix of two bugs.

1. Google is shipping a broken version of the *no* thumb version of the library (i.e. the symbols  are missing). See this [bug report](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2079) for more details (read the last few comments).
2. MonoTouch had issues with libraries that includes thumb instructions. This is fixed in the current beta releases (so it should not be an issue once MonoTouch 5.2 is released). See this [second bug](http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=707) report for details.